# Registration of COM Components on Team Foundation Services (Azure)

Tags: azure-devops

One of my projects requires that a COM server be registered on the build machine.  My first (and only) lame attempt was a simple pre-build step, but I assumed that would not work in the cloud, and I was correct.  Problem is, I need to use this component, I only have a binary, and I'm a bit stumped as to what to do.

The error message is predictable:

> The command "regsvr32 /s "path_to_dll" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.

TFS Azure is in preview at the moment, so I'm not sure how many people have experience with it yet. I posted the same question on the official forums and have not yet received a response.  Searching did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, just need to reference the interop assembly instead of directly referencing the native DLL.  Problem solved.